# Creating a prefixed sequence in one line

Tags: c++, stl, boost

Given the initialized variables `unsigned a`, `unsigned b` with `b > a` and `std::vector<std::string> strings` of size `b-a`. How can I fill `strings` with the elements e.g. `"x3" "x4" "x5" "x6"` (in case `a=3` and `b=7`) for arbitrary `a` and `b` with one C++ command (meaning *one semicolon at all :)*)?

Comment: Should it be a Community Wiki?

Comment: Want someone to do your homework for you? Just label it a "Challenge". I also need a fence painted. http://ensign.ftlcomm.com/people/TomNhuck/ted.html

Comment: Err. A challenge? what's the prize?

Comment: Isn't using boost somewhat like using more than one semicolon? I think it totally is!

Comment: Rupert, this sounds like a Code Golf and you should edit your question to mark this as Community Wiki.

Comment: What is the concern lately with using the least amount of lines in C++?  My belief is that the line count is the least of concern and readability is higher (and also the fact the compilers will optimize your code whether it be one line or many).  Also, I've found writing code with multiple lines helps debugging and setting of breakpoints. :-)

Comment: didn't know about community wiki, thanks for the info. And this is not a homework, I just like these simple to asked questions with a maybe not simple answer. You can learn a lot about C++, and the use of the STL as well as of Boost about it.

Comment: @Thomas: For me it seems sometimes to be the STL way of doing it. There are lots of STL algorithms which are suitable for many purposes when using the right functors. And for me this is readable to, because I can extract the use of the name of the STL algorithm (like `find`, `copy`, `transform`, ...) instead of a `for` block.

Comment: In my experience the lowest line count usually equals the most readability as well. At least when no obscure hackery is used, but rather using just efficient control structures and a nominal amount of whitespace. Because of this I periodically write my code again, to make it shorter and to keep it maintainable.

Comment: Brothers and Sisters! Behold the consequences of Sin! We have *permitted* code golf in our midst, and now we are punished for our deeds!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too challenging...

```
std::transform(
    boost::make_counting_iterator(a), boost::make_counting_iterator(b), 
    strings.begin(), 
    "x" + boost::lambda::bind(boost::lexical_cast<std::string, unsigned int>, 
                              boost::lambda::_1));
```

Comment: +1 Probably the intended answer if you are not supposed to modify `a`. But would you seriously use something like this in practice?

Comment: I don't think it's so bad, I've seen people abuse `boost::lambda` in much worst ways. But yes, in this case a simple for loop would be simpler to write and more readable.

Comment: Since `strings` in the example is already preinitialized, a `strings.begin()` would be more suitable and correct, but anyway this is easier than an approach with boost.bind I tried. I like the STL way of doing this, but the `while` loop is a nice answer to see that sometimes it is easy not to see the _easy_ way anymore :)

Answer (score 8):

What a challenge!

```
while (a < b) strings.push_back('x' + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(a++));
```

Also, compare verbosity with Manuel's answer :)

Answer (score 6):

`#define IM_NOT_A_SEMICOLON_REALLY ;` then proceed at will.

Answer (score 3):

a derivate of UncleBen's answer but using only the STL

```
while( a < b ) vStrings.push_back( 'x' + ( (std::stringstream&)( std::stringstream() << a++ ) ).str() );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BOOST_FOREACH(std::string & str, strings) str = "x" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(a++);
```

Comment: I see you have reverted my change to `lexical_cast<string>(a++)`. Where in the reference (or in C++ in general) does it say that the template argument for a function can be deduced for the return type? All I get is: "no matching function for call to 'lexical_cast(int)'"

Answer (score 1):

Abusing comma operators, which are obviously not semicolons:

```
while (a<b) {
   char s[12],
        t = (snprintf(s, 11, "x%d", a++), strings.push_back(s), 0);
}
```